# How to set class to "current-page" on the currently viewed single post within a CPT

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, query-posts, single

I have a custom post type, "case". I'm currently editing the single-case.php file and in my sidebar I have the following piece of code:

```
<?php
$case_query = array (
    'post_type' => 'case',
    'showposts' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => ASC
);
query_posts($case_query);
if ( have_posts() ) {
    echo '<div class="case-list">';
    while (have_posts()) {
        the_post();
        $title = get_the_title();
        $url = get_permalink(); ?>
        <div class="case-list-item">
            <div class="ico"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-angle-right"></i></div>
            <div class="link"><a href="<?php echo $url; ?>"><?php echo $title; ?></a></div>
        </div>

        <?php
    }
    echo '</div>';
    wp_reset_query();
}
?>
```

What I'm wondering is, how do I check which of the posts in above while-loop is the currently viewed post and then add a class of "current" to it? Or am I doing this all kinds of wrong?..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

Before the declaration of `$case_query`, I declare the active page id, like so: `$active_page = get_the_ID();`. Then, in the while loop after `the_post();` I add the following:

```
$activeclass = '';
if (get_the_ID() === $active_page) {
    $activeclass = 'current-page';
}
```

I also add the `$activeclass` to the `.case-list-item` div: `<div class="case-list-item <?php echo $activeclass; ?>">`

Solved.